# Does onDraw() calls automatically except on loading and when calling a invalidate()?

Tags: android

I wanted to know whether the onDraw method get called without the programmers knowledge. I know that it is called at the first time View is loading and I know it calls when I call invaliade(). But does it calls in any other times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, whenever a parent view is redrawing itself like if the custom view is within a ScrollView whenever you scroll it...